# .htaccess rewrite does not work although file is being accessed

Tags: .htaccess

I am using an htaccess file that has stopped working despite it working well for years but do not know why.  I have confirmed the file is being accessed by using deny all which blocked the site. I just don't know why the rewrite and force https has stopped.

My code is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^ContactUs$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^News$ news.php
RewriteRule ^Timetable$ index.php
RewriteRule ^room-hire$ index.php
RewriteRule ^Practitioner/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ practitioner.php?Practitioner=$1
RewriteRule ^Clinic/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ clinics.php?Clinic=$1
RewriteRule ^MoreInformation/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ClinicMoreDetail.php?clinicSlug=$1
RewriteRule ^Story/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ news-story.php?slug=$1
RewriteRule ^Archive/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ news-date.php?year=$1&month=$2
RewriteRule ^Category/News$ news-category.php?cat=1
RewriteRule ^Category/Courses-&-Seminars$ news-category.php?cat=2
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your htaccess rule file. Could you please do let us know what url you are hitting and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  

If I go to http://mydomain.co.uk I do not get server https://mydomain.co.uk

If I go to my domain.co.uk/ContactUs I get a 404 Error however if I go to mydomain.co.uk/contact.php I am able to see the page

Comment: Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess` file? eg. `<IfModule>` wrappers? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? Have you recently added a CDN like Cloudflare or front-end proxy? "working well for years" - although it's not strictly correct. Your first rule (www to non-www) is redirecting back to `http` - so this will result in an unnecessary (slow) double redirect when requesting the www subdomain. Also, the two "floating" `RewriteCond` directives are missplaced and should probably be removed entirely.

Comment: I don’t have any other <if module> wrappers. This is the only .htaccess file in the entire site. I haven’t added any new cdn. What I meant was is that these fairly simple rewrites for url changes had been working as expected for over 4 years maybe longer

Comment: Do you have access to the Apache server config? Try adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` at the top of the `.htaccess` file. To clarify, when you say, "using deny all which blocked the site" - you presumably mean `Deny from all` and this resulted in a 403 Forbidden response (not a 500 or some other error)?

Comment: The hosting is a shared server hosting and as such I don't have access to the Apache server config.  I used 'deny from all' which gave me a 403 Forbidden Response in order to prove that the .htaccess file was being accessed.  I have added Options +FollowSymLinks as suggested and Im still getting a 404.  I have asked the person who owns the hosting package to contact their Tech Support to determine if there is an issue with mod_rewrite on their package

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to contact your webhost. It sounds as if the mod_rewrite directives are being completely "ignored"?! Which doesn't make much sense. If mod_rewrite was not enabled and in the absence of `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrappers, you would get a 500 error.

Comment: Your hoster maight have this configuration:   AllowOverride None

Comment: @jacouh Although `Deny from all` directives are "working" in `.htaccess`, so it can't be `AllowOverride None`. It could perhaps be `AllowOverride Limit` or simply not including `FileInfo` (required for mod_rewrite), but then the mod_rewrite directives would ordinarily trigger a "fatal" 500 error, unless the host has also disabled "fatal" errors (eg. `Nonfatal=Override`)!? Yes, they could have done something like this, but it's now in the realm of "deliberate action" rather than "accidental misconfiguration", which would be unusual on a shared server with potentially 100s of sites. (?)